# c_str() returns empty string

Tags: c++, google-nativeclient

For some reason c_str() returns empty string, the parameter `const chart**out_function` will hold a method name for file operations like `fopen` so basically what I do is converting a string I have to c_str() but I get an empty string below is how I do the calls

In this part I just prepare a dictionary with an operation name, as you can notice I am just sending "fopen" as string

```
    pp::VarDictionary fileOp;
    pp::VarArray args;
    args.Set(0, "filename.txt");
    args.Set(1, "wb");
    fileOp.Set("args", args);
    fileOp.Set("cmd", "fopen");
```

This function will parse the dictionary sent above and return the name of the function in `out_function` and `args` in `out_params`

```
    int ParseMessage(pp::Var message, const char** out_function,
        pp::Var* out_params) {
```

I use this line of code to convert the string to c_string, but It returns empty text

```
*out_function =  cmd_value.AsString().c_str();
```

here is the full code, it is based on Google Native Client but at the same time it is standard C/C++ code

http://pastebin.com/S4P8aZqL

Comment: You are storing a pointer to a destroyed temporary.

Comment: Don't spam tags. There is no language "C/C++" and the snippets are clearly C++, not C.

Comment: It relates to all three of them, I am not trying to spam

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa Coding in C++ is not sufficient reason to tag C. You're using std::string, namespaces, and OOP. That's not C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result of `c_str()` is only valid as long as the `std::string` object that produced that result is valid.

In your case, `AsString()` call produces a *temporary* `std::string` object which is then immediately destroyed. After that the result of that `c_str()` call no longer makes any sense. Trying to access the memory pointed by that pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Don't attempt to store the pointer returned by `c_str()`. If you need that string as a C-string for an extended period of time, allocate memory buffer for it yourself and copy the result of `c_str()` to that buffer.

Another (much better) idea would be not to rush the conversion to C-string. Return the result as `std::string` and call `c_str()` on it at the very last moment: when you reall really really need a C-string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is the code I used to solve this issue 

`*out_function =  strdup(cmd_value.AsString().c_str());`

Comment: @Mohammad Abu Musa: That will solve it, but now you have a `malloc`ed block of raw memory to manage manually. As I said, a much better idea would be to switch to using `std::string` until the last moment.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that, I think using `std::string` is a much better approach