# Workaround for PyByteArray_AsString from bytearray that contains null characters

Tags: python, c++

I've got some buffer of data, a `PyByteArray`, that I want to extract the `char *` from. I want to then take that char* and create a stringstream from it.

```
void CKKSwrapper::DeserializeContext(PyObject *obj) {
    // Is a PyByteArray object as determined by https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytearray.html#c.PyByteArray_Check
    PyObject_Print(obj, stdout, Py_PRINT_RAW);  // 1
    const char *s = PyByteArray_AsString(obj);  // 2
    std::cout << "Converted bytearray to string" << std::endl;  // 3 
    std::cout << s << std::endl;  // 4


    std::istringstream is(s);  // 5
    lbcrypto::CryptoContext<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly> new_cc; // 6
    Serial::Deserialize(new_cc, is, SerType::BINARY); // 7
}
```

The 2nd line `const char *s = PyByteArray_AsString(obj);` outputs a single character. From a previous question [C++ c_str of std::string returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934538/c-c-str-of-stdstring-returns-empty/66934704#66934704) (the title isn't accurate), I know for a fact that the underlying data for the input object, `PyObject *obj`, has `NULL` characters in it.

Based on the [API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytearray.html#byte-array-objects) I don't see any immediate solutions. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Note: From the current codebase I need to go from

`Server: (C++ -> Python) -> (sockets) -> Client: (Python -> C++)`

so I cant really get around the PyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the description of all the PyByteArray](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytearray.html) functions, you will find a useful function called `PyByteArray_Size`. This gives you the size of the array.

`std::string` has many constructors. One of them constructs the `std::string` from a beginning and an ending iterator. A pointer meets those qualifications. So, you should be able to construct an entire `std::string` accordingly:

```
const char *ptr = PyByteArray_AsString(obj);
size_t n=PyByteArray_Size(obj);

std::string s{ptr, ptr+n};

std::cout << s << std::endl;
```